# Rename a column in MS Access dynamically using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Is there is any way by which we can rename a column in MS Access dynamically from C#?
I know its simple in SQL Server but which is the best approach to do the same in Access programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

For an Access 2003 database file, you can use good old Jet DAO if your application is running as 32-bit:

```csharp
// test data
string tableName = "Members";
string oldFieldName = "Photo";
string newFieldName = "Photograph";

// COM Reference required in C# project:
//     Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
//
var dbe = new DAO.DBEngine();
DAO.Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb");
DAO.Field fld = db.TableDefs[tableName].Fields[oldFieldName];
fld.Name = newFieldName;
db.Close();
```

To operate on an .accdb file, or to perform the operation from a C# application that is running as 64-bit, the newer [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (a.k.a "ACE") needs to be installed. Then the code would be:

```csharp
// test data
string tableName = "Members";
string oldFieldName = "Photo";
string newFieldName = "Photograph";

// COM Reference required in C# project:
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\accdbTest.accdb");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Field fld = db.TableDefs[tableName].Fields[oldFieldName];
fld.Name = newFieldName;
db.Close();
```